# how to use OR operator in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i am using code igniter and i want to get the record from db using OR operator so can anyone help me how to use OR operator in where clause

getting record from db where code is equal to 12 or 21 and status is 1

```
public static function front_page_ads() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $array = array('status' => 1 , 'code'=>'12' OR 'code'=>'21');
        $CI->db->where($array);
        $CI->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $CI->db->limit(3);
        $q = $CI->db->get('international');
        $r = $q->result();
        return $r;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
    $array = array('status' => 1);
    $CI->db->where($array);
    $ci->db->where("(code='12' OR code='21' )");
    $CI->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $CI->db->limit(3);
    $q = $CI->db->get('international');
    $r = $q->result();
```

**or_where**  : multiple instances are joined by OR

```
    $CI->db->where($array);
    $ci->db->or_where("code='12'");
    $ci->db->or_where("code='21'");
```

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it withe green tick it's useful for future user reference .@GauharAli

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write **OR**.

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

or you can use

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->or_where('id', $id);
```

In your code :

```
public static function front_page_ads() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $code_arr=array('12','21');
        $CI->db->where('status',1);
        $CI->db->where_in('code', $code_arr);
        $CI->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $CI->db->limit(3);
        $q = $CI->db->get('international');
        $r = $q->result();
        return $r;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

simply:
        $this->db->where("status","live")->or_where("status","dead");

```
                               or
    $this->db->where("(status='live' OR status='dead')");
```